# How to use flutter barcode plugin to display a qr barcode?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to generate and display a QR barcode on my page. I found a plugin [`barcode`](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode) and read its examples. But I just cannot display it. Exception info and my work is below.

Error

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter ( 5048): Unable to load asset: <svg viewBox="0.00000 0.00000 197.52533 197.00000"
I/flutter ( 5048): xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M 0.26267 0.00000 h 65.66667 v 9.38095 h -65.66667 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 84.69124 0.00000 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 103.45314 0.00000 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -18.76190 z M 131.59600 0.00000 h 65.66667 v 9.38095 h -65.66667 z M 0.26267 9.38095 h 9.38095 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 56.54838 9.38095 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 84.69124 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 131.59600 9.38095 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 187.88171
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 0.26267 18.76190 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 19.02457 18.76190 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 56.54838 18.76190 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 75.31029 18.76190 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 103.45314 18.76190 h 18.76190 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 131.59600 18.76190 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 150.35790 18.76190 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 187.88171 18.76190 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 0.26267
I/flutter ( 5048): 28.14286 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 19.02457 28.14286 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 56.54838 28.14286 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 84.69124 28.14286 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 103.45314 28.14286 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 131.59600 28.14286 h 9.38095 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 150.35790 28.14286 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 187.88171 28.14286 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 0.26267 37.52381 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 19.02457
I/flutter ( 5048): 37.52381 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 56.54838 37.52381 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 94.07219 37.52381 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 112.83410 37.52381 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 131.59600 37.52381 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 150.35790 37.52381 h 28.14286 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 187.88171 37.52381 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 0.26267 46.90476 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 56.54838 46.90476 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 112.83410
I/flutter ( 5048): 46.90476 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 131.59600 46.90476 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 187.88171 46.90476 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 0.26267 56.28571 h 65.66667 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -65.66667 z M 75.31029 56.28571 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 94.07219 56.28571 h 9.38095 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 112.83410 56.28571 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 131.59600 56.28571 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 65.66667 v 9.38095 h -65.66667 z M 75.31029 65.66667 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 103.45314
I/flutter ( 5048): 65.66667 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 0.26267 75.04762 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 37.78648 75.04762 h 75.04762 v 9.38095 h -75.04762 z M 122.21505 75.04762 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -18.76190 z M 169.11981 75.04762 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 9.64362 84.42857 h 18.76190 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 47.16743 84.42857 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 84.69124 84.42857 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 131.59600 84.42857 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 169.11981
I/flutter ( 5048): 84.42857 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 0.26267 93.80952 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 47.16743 93.80952 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 94.07219 93.80952 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 112.83410 93.80952 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 150.35790 93.80952 h 9.38095 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 187.88171 93.80952 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 9.64362 103.19048 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 65.92933 103.19048 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 94.07219
I/flutter ( 5048): 103.19048 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 131.59600 103.19048 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 169.11981 103.19048 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 19.02457 112.57143 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 56.54838 112.57143 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 84.69124 112.57143 h 9.38095 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 112.83410 112.57143 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 131.59600 112.57143 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 150.35790 112.57143 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 169.11981
I/flutter ( 5048): 112.57143 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 75.31029 121.95238 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z
I/flutter ( 5048): M 103.45314 121.95238 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 122.21505 121.95238 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 140.97695 121.95238 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 159.73886 121.95238 h 9.38095 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 187.88171 121.95238 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 0.26267 131.33333 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 65.66667 v 9.38095 h -65.66667 z M 75.31029 131.33333 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 103.45314
I/flutter ( 5048): 131.33333 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 122.21505 131.33333 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z
I/flutter ( 5048): M 159.73886 131.33333 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 187.88171 131.33333 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 0.26267 140.71429 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 56.54838 140.71429 h 9.38095 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 75.31029 140.71429 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 103.45314 140.71429 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 140.97695 140.71429 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 0.26267
I/flutter ( 5048): 150.09524 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 19.02457 150.09524 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 56.54838 150.09524 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 75.31029 150.09524 h 37.52381 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -37.52381 z M 122.21505 150.09524 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 159.73886 150.09524 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 187.88171 150.09524 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 0.26267
I/flutter ( 5048): 159.47619 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 19.02457 159.47619 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M
I/flutter ( 5048): 56.54838 159.47619 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 94.07219 159.47619 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 131.59600 159.47619 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 169.11981 159.47619 h 18.76190 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 0.26267 168.85714 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 19.02457 168.85714 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 56.54838 168.85714 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 75.31029
I/flutter ( 5048): 168.85714 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 112.83410 168.85714 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z
I/flutter ( 5048): M 150.35790 168.85714 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 187.88171 168.85714 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 0.26267 178.23810 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 56.54838 178.23810 h 9.38095 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 75.31029 178.23810 h 28.14286 v 9.38095 h -28.14286 z M 131.59600 178.23810 h
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 169.11981 178.23810 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z M 0.26267
I/flutter ( 5048): 187.61905 h 65.66667 v 9.38095 h -65.66667 z M 75.31029 187.61905 h 18.76190 v 9.38095 h -18.76190 z
I/flutter ( 5048): M 112.83410 187.61905 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 131.59600 187.61905 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h
I/flutter ( 5048): -9.38095 z M 150.35790 187.61905 h 9.38095 v 9.38095 h -9.38095 z M 169.11981 187.61905 h 28.14286 v
I/flutter ( 5048): 9.38095 h -28.14286 z " style="fill: #000000"/><text style="fill: #000000; font-family:
I/flutter ( 5048): &quot;monospace&quot;; font-size: 39.40000px" x="0.00000" y="0.00000"></text></svg>
I/flutter ( 5048):
I/flutter ( 5048): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5048): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter ( 5048): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 5048): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:664:31)
I/flutter ( 5048): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:648:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:359:22)
I/flutter ( 5048): #5      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:499:80)
I/flutter ( 5048): #6      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:106:19)
I/flutter ( 5048): #7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:330:9)
I/flutter ( 5048): #8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.
dart:460:26)
I/flutter ( 5048): #9      SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:41:29)
I/flutter ( 5048): #10     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:457:11)
I/flutter ( 5048): #14     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:449:16)
I/flutter ( 5048): #15     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #16     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1099:16)
I/flutter ( 5048): #17     _ImageState.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1084:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #18     StatefulElement.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4631:11)
I/flutter ( 5048): #19     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #20     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #21     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #22     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #23     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5929:16)
I/flutter ( 5048): #24     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #25     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5817:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #27     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #28     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #29     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #30     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #31     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #32     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #33     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #34     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #35     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #36     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #37     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #38     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5929:16)
I/flutter ( 5048): #39     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #40     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #41     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #42     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #43     StatefulElement.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4632:11)
I/flutter ( 5048): #44     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #45     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #46     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #47     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #48     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #49     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #50     StatefulElement.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4632:11)
I/flutter ( 5048): #51     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #52     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5817:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #53     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #54     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #55     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #56     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #57     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #58     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5817:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #59     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #60     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #61     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #62     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #63     StatefulElement.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4632:11)
I/flutter ( 5048): #64     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #65     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #66     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #67     StatefulElement.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4632:11)
I/flutter ( 5048): #68     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #69     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #70     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #71     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #72     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #73     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #74     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #75     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #76     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #77     StatefulElement.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4632:11)
I/flutter ( 5048): #78     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #79     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5817:14)
I/flutter ( 5048): #80     Element.reassemble (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2990:5)
I/flutter ( 5048): #81     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:13)
I/flutter ( 5048): #82     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4556:14)
```

```dart
Container(
  child: Image.asset(Barcode.qrCode().toSvg(
    widget.result,
    width: ScreenUtil.dpWidth(197),
    height: ScreenUtil.dpHeight(197),
  )),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation of the package you are using. It states

> If you want to display barcodes in a Flutter application, use pub:barcode_widget.

You need to add `barcode_widget` as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml.
Then use the `BarcodeWidget` widget to display your barcode.

```dart
BarcodeWidget(
  barcode: Barcode.qrCode(),
  data: widget.result,
  width: ScreenUtil.dpWidth(197),
  height: ScreenUtil.dpHeight(197),
)
```

---

Your current code does not work as flutter does not natively support displaying SVGs. Additionally, you are passing the unsupported SVG string as the name of an asset. `Image.asset` should only be used for assets, not for dynamically obtained data.

Comment: thanks for your edit and solution. I'm new to both flutter and StackOverflow, another thing could you please tell me how to layout my error info in StackOverflow, I always put it chaotically.  My method is clicked the `”` and paste the info then it looks like my former style.

Comment: @byhuang1998 Use triple backticks "```". You can look at how I edited your question by going to the edit window yourself.